# Eager load on Nova Resource and Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have 2 tables: Product and Categories. Should I declare eager load in Nova Resource like this:

```
// For Product Resource

/**
 * The relationships that should be eager loaded on index queries.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public static $with = ['categories'];
```

or on model like this:

```
// For model App\Product

protected $with = ['categories'];
```

If I do both on resource and model. Will it cause a duplicated query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use barryvdh/laravel-debugbar, you will find all the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have declared it in **Nova Resource** and it resolved my problem.

There is no need to declare it on Model too.